# bwplot median line instead of dot

Tags: r

I am instructed to only use bwplot for the following.  I am instructed to make some adjustments to the aesthetics to make the box plot easier to read.  Using the HH package bwplot, the default is to have a dot in the middle of the box plot.  What I would like to do is change this dot to a line to show the median instead.  Below is the code I have thus far, but I am unable to find out how to change the dot into a line.  Note, if you install the HH package, I am using the dataset 'draft70mn' within that package.

I do understand that this may not actually be possible with the package being used.  However, if it is, I would like to learn how to do it with this package.

```
data(draft70mn) # calls the dataset - the dataset is named draft70mn
head(draft70mn) # displays the first 6 lines of the dataset

draft70 <- stack(draft70mn) 
# reformats the dataset and renames it draft70

draft70$quarter <- factor(c(rep(1, 93), rep(2, 93),
                            rep(3, 93), rep(4, 93)))
# adds a new variable to the dataset draft70, this new variable is
# labeled quarter and it identifies the quarter of the year for each 
# date

draft70$ind <- factor(draft70$ind, levels=names(draft70mn))
# makes the variable ind (month) a factor with levels.  This tells R 
#that the names of the month have a meaningful order (Jan, Feb,..) 
#and should not be placed in alphabetical order

draft70 <- draft70[!is.na(draft70$values), ]
#removes missing data, that is, removes day 31 in months with 
#only 30 days or less    

bwplot(values ~ ind, data = draft70, arrange = TRUE,
       panel = panel.bwplot.superpose, groups = ind,
       ylab = 'Draft Number',
       xlab = 'Month')
```

Any help with this is great.

Comment: `values` and `ind` are not in the `draft70mn` data set. You need to provide where those values came from or how you calculated them. Otherwise you haven't provided a reproducible example.

Comment: @MHammer I have included that code now.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that adding "pch = '|' will do the trick.  The final code for the bwplot would then be:

```
bwplot(values ~ ind, data = draft70, arrange = TRUE,
   panel = panel.bwplot.superpose, groups = ind,
   ylab = 'Draft Number',
   xlab = 'Month',
   pch = '|') ##Omitting this will result in the line reverting back to a dot.
```

Photo of output below.

[image]